# Sum transactional numeric API Responses

Tags: ruby, hash, sum

I am making about 5000 transactional API calls, and I need to send a log in an email at the end with a summary of what happened. Each API call returns a response like this:

```
response = {
  :add_record_to_list_response => {
    :return => {
      :failure_message => nil,
      :upload_duplicates_count => "0",
      :upload_errors_count => "0",
      :warnings_count => nil,
      :call_now_queued => "0",
      :crm_records_inserted => "1",
      :crm_records_updated => "0",
      :list_name => "DIS Membership NPS 2013",
      :list_records_deleted => "0",
      :list_records_inserted => "1"
    },
    :"@xmlns:ns2" => "http://service.admin.ws.five9.com/",
    :"@xmlns:ns3" => "http://service.admin.ws.five9.com/v1/"
  }
}
```

I want to sum up each number in this response. What's the most efficient way for me to do that? I don't want to log each response individually, and I don't want to store the numbers as I feel like that could cause issues down the road. This is what I'm thinking now:

```
upload_duplicates_count = 0
upload_duplicates_count = upload_duplicates_count +
  response[:add_record_to_list_response][:return][:upload_duplicates_count]
```

And I would do that for each number in the response. It just seems like there should be a better way to go about that.

Comment: Do you want to sum only `:upload_duplicates_count` for each hash ?

Comment: I want to sum each value represented in the hash that is numeric.

Comment: Which ones are "numeric" according to your definition? Is `:warnings_count` excluded because it is `nil`?

Comment: Good question, I'm not really sure why it's returning nil instead of zero. Nil values should be considered as zeros, and the only thing I DONT want to sum is the `failure_message` and `list_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a hash:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
```

and repeat the following for each response:

```
response[:add_record_to_list_response][:return]
.reject{|k, _| k == :failure_message or k == :list_name}
.each{|k, v| counts[k] += v.to_i}
```

After repeating it for all responses, the values will be added up within each value in the `count` hash. For example, after the example you have, you would get:

```
{
  :upload_duplicates_count => 0,
  :upload_errors_count     => 0,
  :warnings_count          => 0,
  :call_now_queued         => 0,
  :crm_records_inserted    => 1,
  :crm_records_updated     => 0,
  :list_records_deleted    => 0,
  :list_records_inserted   => 1
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - Seems like a good solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Me too. I don't understand why. Glad you understood it is good.

Comment: I had a (not-so-harmful) mistake. Please see my edit.

Comment: It wasn't a mistake, actually. You could go with either way, before or after my edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are, of course, lots of ways to do this and I would think robustness or maintainability would be greater concerns than efficiency. That said, here's an approach to consider:

```
def update_counts(counts, response)
  response[:add_record_to_list_response][:return].each do |key, value|
    next unless value.nil? || /^\d+$/ =~ value
    counts[key] = (counts[key] || 0) + value.to_i
  end
end
```

where `counts` is a hash of the counts and is initialized to `{}`. This version provides an alternative to explicitly identifying which keys you want to exclude/include.

Comment: It looks like it is clear which keys do not return numerals, and for a key that usually returns a numeral string, the only exceptional case is when it returns `nil`, in which case it does not harm to add `nil.to_i`, which is `0`. And that is actually what the OP requested in the comment. Suppose in every case `:warnings_count` has the value `nil`. With your code, you will end up with a hash missing `:warnings_count`. That is not what the OP requested.

Comment: Actually, the OP requested the sum of all integers, and it was only in his later comment that he said he wanted `nil` treated as an integer.  I'll update in light of that, but I still think the code is less brittle if it doesn't explicitly exclude values based on key. In any event, it's certainly his choice. :-)

Comment: I just realized that your code (both before and after the edit) may not be valid Ruby code. Look carefully.